# Issuing multiple commands on exit in vim

Tags: vim

I have a written a little shortcut to push to git from vim (`nnoremap <C-g>p :!git push<CR>`), and was wondering if it's possible to chain commands together on exit.

In this case, i'd like a *goToBbed* command, which pushes to git and saves and closes: something that combines `:!git push` and `:x` -- is this possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a mapping (which is basically recorded typed keys), just append the additional command:

```
:nnoremap <C-g>p :!git push<CR>:x<CR>
```

For a *command*, you have to use the *command separator* `|`, or (for more complex stuff), delegate to a custom *function*. There's one caveat: Some commands cannot be chained (`:!` is one of them), and need to be wrapped in `:execute` to do this, e.g.

```
:command GoToBed execute '!git push' | xit
```

(Note: Custom commands must start with an uppercase letter.)

Comment: wonderful: `GoToBed` is exactly the custom command i am looking for. A _noob_ question: any reason to prefer `xit` to `x`?

Comment: Glad I could help. Choosing the full `xit` over the abbreviated `x` is just a matter of style. As you're writing that command definition only once, I prefer the fully spelled-out version, as it's clearer.

Comment: is it possible to make this work in the case where i have multiple tabs open?

Comment: Yes, use `:xall` instead of `:xit`.

Comment: will that repeat the `!git push` for each of the tabs?

Comment: No, that will just exit from all tabs. You need `:tabdo` / `:windo` (also in combination if you're using window splits).

Comment: thanks. I settled on `execute ':tabdo !git push' | xall` -- after a fair bit of fiddling. not sure if it's the _best_ way, but it does the trick.